# EF Core .Include() is not loading related data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a REST API application in .NET Core 7 using ASP.NET and EF Core. In my database, I have a User entity and related Address entity with a one-to-one relationship, as well as Categories entity with a one-to-many relationship.

User.cs:

```
public class User : AggregateRoot<UserId>
{
    public UserId Id { get; private set; }

    public Account Account { get; private set; }
    public Address Address { get; private set; }
    
    public readonly List<Category> Categories;
    public readonly List<CurrencyAccount> CurrencyAccounts;
    
    public UserEmail Email { get; private set; }
    public UserName Name { get; private set; }
    public UserPhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; private set; }
    public UserGender Gender { get; private set; }
    public UserBirthDate BirthDate { get; private set; }
    
    internal User(UserId id, UserEmail email, UserName name, UserPhoneNumber phoneNumber,
        UserGender gender, UserBirthDate birthDate, Address address)
    {
        Id = id;
        Email = email;
        Name = name;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        Gender = gender;
        BirthDate = birthDate;
        Address = address;
        
        AddEvent(new UserCreated(this));
    }

    private User()
    {

    }

    /* Below methods to provide acces to aggregate */

}
```

Address.cs

```
public class Address
{
    //private Regex universalPostalCodeRegex = new(@"^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\- ]{0,10}[a-z0-9]$");
    // private Regex polandPostalCodeRegex = new(@"^\d{2}-\d{3}$");
    //private Regex houseNumberRegex = new(@"^\d{1,4}[A-Z]$");

    public AddressCountry Country{ get; }
    public AddressCity City { get; }
    public AddressStreet Street { get; }
    public AddressPostalCode PostalCode { get; }
    public AddressHouseNumber HouseNumber { get; }
    public AddressApartmentNumber? ApartmentNumber{ get; }

    public Address(string country, string city, string street, string postalCode, string houseNumber)
    {


        Country = country;
        City = city;
        Street = street;
        PostalCode = postalCode;
        HouseNumber = houseNumber;
    }

    private Address()
    {
    }
    
    public Address(string country, string city, string street, string postalCode, string houseNumber, string apartmentNumber) 
        : this(country, city, street, postalCode, houseNumber)
    {
        ApartmentNumber = apartmentNumber;
    }    
}
```

Category.cs

```
public class Category
{
    public CategoryId Id { get; }
    public CategoryName Name { get; init; }

    public Category(CategoryId id, CategoryName name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Relation definitions:

```
        //Address
        builder
            .HasOne(u => u.Address)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Address>()
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        //Category
        builder
            .HasMany(u => u.Categories)
            .WithOne()
            .IsRequired(false)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

SQL generated by EF Core:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT u."Id", u."AccountId", u."BirthDate", u."Email", u."Gender", u."Name", u."PhoneNumber", a."Id", a."ApartmentNumber", a."City", a."Country", a."HouseNumber", a."PostalCode", a."Street", a."UserId"
      FROM "moneyDB"."Users" AS u
      LEFT JOIN "moneyDB"."Addresses" AS a ON u."Id" = a."UserId"
      ORDER BY u."Id", a."Id"
      LIMIT 2
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT c."Id", c."Name", c."UserId", t."Id", t."Id0"
      FROM (
          SELECT u."Id", a."Id" AS "Id0"
          FROM "moneyDB"."Users" AS u
          LEFT JOIN "moneyDB"."Addresses" AS a ON u."Id" = a."UserId"
          LIMIT 1
      ) AS t
      INNER JOIN "moneyDB"."Categories" AS c ON t."Id" = c."UserId"
      ORDER BY t."Id", t."Id0"
```

Method that doesn't work:

```
    public async Task<Domain.Aggregates.User> GetAsync(UserId id)
        => await _users
            .Include(u => u.Address )
            .Include(u => u.Categories)
            .AsSplitQuery()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

The issue arises when I try to read a User along with at least one related entity (attempting to load two ends up with the same result). The program doesn't throw any errors, however, the user is returned with null values in the Address and Categories fields.

Removing the `.AsSplitQuery()` doesn't help and, in fact, breaks the program, causing an error that shouldn't occur at all.

I have checked the consistency between the defined classes and the database schema. I found no discrepancies.

Additionally, I have a part of the application handling queries. I use Dapper there, and it works well, loading data as expected.

Comment: I would think that your method would always `throw` assuming there is more than 1 `User` in your DB (you're not filtering the users by `id`).

Comment: See docs: [Entity types with constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors). Quote: _EF Core cannot set navigation properties (such as Blog or Posts above) using a constructor_. Try removing `Address` from the constructor. Make `Categories` a property instead of field.

Comment: @WBuck im doing it but i was trying just all things that come to my head and dont remember to put it here again

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  unfortunately it wasn’t the problem. I changed it and this still working the same. I have parameterless constructors as a protection from situation that you described.

Comment: Show the changed version.

Comment: What is the exception when you remove `AsSplitQuery`? There should be no exception so it would seem that `AsSplitQuery` may be hiding the actual cause of the problem from you.

Comment: Also, for a start, make the `private` default constructors `protected` and initialize your collection navigation properties. `public List<Category> Categories { get; protected set; } = new List<Category>();` Make your other `private` setters `protected` if you want to restrict their access like for DDD. Keep in mind that the entity class should serve Entity Framework first, then consider your desired app domain restrictions. Being overly restrictive can interfere with allowing EF to do its job and populate entities correctly.